# Google Analytics api query result missing dates?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to use google analytic's query api to build the last week line chart.

```
dimensions: ga:date

sort: ga:date
```

but I found the result is missing some date: ex: (1/1 ~ 1/6, should have 7 day's data)

there are only have 1/1, 1/2, 1/5, 1/6 (lack of 1/3, 1/4..)

how to fill the missing data?

I found there is some infomation:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/backfill_dates#backfil

but its java version. Is there any solution for client side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, by default Google Analytics won't return rows if associated metrics are equal to 0 (e.g. if you have a website with low or hit-miss traffic, and you query for traffic on daily basis, you will see those gaps).

The [`v4 reporting API`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.include_empty_rows) has the `includeEmptyRows` parameter (by default set to `false`) which should prevent this behaviour:

> If set to false, the response does not include rows if all the
> retrieved metrics are equal to zero. The default is false which will
> exclude these rows.

As for filling those gaps with a client-side loop, just identify the missing dates, generate empty rows for those missing dates, and merge the 2 datasets.

Comment: I know the includeEmptyRows, but It seems no associated with this case, So I must generate the missing row by myself?

Comment: i also try `includeEmptyRows` and `keepEmptyRows` based on docs in GA4, but seems does not work. Any idea?